# How would I dynamically generate a page title based on the active navigation tab?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using php includes to call in different sections to pages but some of these need to have some different content.

I am trying to set the text that is within an h tag to be the same as the currently clicked navigation item.

Im currently just setting the current page in the navigation section and then again at the top of the page I want to name, defining a variable then calling it within the title.

Navigation Include:

```
 <div>
 <ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="about.php"><?php ($currentPage =='about')?>About</a> . 
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

About us page:

```
<?php ($currentPage =='about');
  $title ='About Us'
?>
```

which has the

`<?php include("includes/titles/page-title.php"); ?>`   within it, this is also called on different pages and within this include I have

```
<h2 class="title-center"><?php echo $title ?></h2>
```

I also have a contact page where I have the same include but need a different title:

```
<?php ($currentPage =='contact');
$title ='Contact'
?>
```

Comment: So, it's just one page and different tabs?

Comment: What is `($currentPage =='about');` supposed to do?

Comment: @AJ no sorry didn't make that clear, I have two pages, about.php and then contact.php but they both use the same header include (include/header.php) and (include/page-title.php). But I want the h tag text that is in the page-title include to be the same as the page that is active, that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

**Your requirement:**

*Need respective page headers for every page*

**Solution:**

1) Take an array of page headers

2) Key should be `$currentPage` from url.

3) Value should be required Page Title.

4) Check if page title is set for `$currentPage`, if set, print it.

Simple...

And Code:

```
<?php
$pageHeaders = [];
$pageHeaders['about'] = 'About Us';
$pageHeaders['contact'] = 'Contact Us';
...
?>
```

Now, print your page header:

```
<h2 class="title-center">
<?php
$title = 'Your Default Page Title';
if (isset($pageHeaders[$currentPage])) {
 echo $pageHeaders[$currentPage];
}
else {
 echo $title;
}
?>
</h2>
```

Note: You can also, create dynamic page navigation with the same kind of array.

The key should be url and the value should be the text.

Loop over it and print navigation menu.